# How to interpret box plot and histogram together?

Tags: statistics, histogram, boxplot, median, percentile

[image]

I have these plots, both made out of the same data. But I feel that they don't make sense (correct me if I'm wrong).

In the box plot, the 50th percentile value/ median is 11.7

As far as I understand, this means that 50% of the entire data is less than this value which is 11.7

The size of data is 3404 data points.
Which means that 3404/2 = 1702 data points are less than 11.7, right?

But in the histogram, the no. of values in the 0-20 bin is 1257.
The no. of values in 20-40 bin is 311.
The no. of values in 40-60 bin is 113.

The total data points between 0-60 are 1681 ~ 49% of the entire data.

Now I'm confused because when ~50% of data lies between 0-60, how can the median be 11.7?

Can someone please shed some light on this? I might be terribly wrong and would be grateful for anyone who helps!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the statistics of your box plot do not include the numerous outliers. It may be the case that you have enough outliers to create the conditions that you describe. In fact, the maximum of your box plot only goes up to 60.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its not just about the box plot though. Even when I calculate the median separately, its the same value of 11.7